# How do I get a list from set in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

This seems to work in python 2.7, but not python 3.  Is there an easy way to make a set a list in python 3 that I am missing?  Thanks in advance.

```
    mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
    list(set(mylist))
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Sorry if this has been asked before, I did a quick search and didn't see an answer specific to python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(set(...))` works fine. The error indicates the 3.x version of the code has a variable called `list` or `set`, shadowing the built-in function. Perhaps you renamed `mylist` to `list`? Rest assured, that mistake would provoke the exact same error message in Python 2.

Comment: Geesh, you are totally right.  Sorry to be a flake.  I will delete this.